# how can I set relative line numbers upon entering nerdtree on vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying this snippet, but nothing happens. The nerdtree buffer still has no line numbering whatsoever.

`autocmd BufEnter nerd* set rnu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
:let g:NERDTreeShowLineNumbers=1
:autocmd BufEnter NERD_* setlocal rnu
```

Comment: Hum, still nothing happens.

Comment: @ninrod Turns out I didn't have the latest version of NERDTree. I installed it, found the issue, and revised my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm.